# How to optimise this at maximum?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, fetch

I need to fetch a ressource very very often (it's sensors so to detect a change it is necessary).
I wanted to know if my code bellow can be optimized.

**The code :**

```
const _sensors = {};
fetch('http://localhost:9797/poll')
            .then(result => result.text())
            .then(body => {
                const arr = body.split('\n');
                for (let i = 0, iMax = arr.length; i < iMax; i++) {
                    const split = arr[i].split(' ');
                    _sensors[split[0]] = split[1];
                }
            });
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The limiting factor here is the request roundtrip, so I doubt there are meaningful improvements to speed that can be done here.

Comment: if you can change the server part, might be good to actually implement websockets as with that, you no longer need to keep pulling, when there's data, it will be send to all registered clients...

Comment: Optimise by not doing polling, but do the change detection on the server side and get a stream of events?

Comment: The problem is that i haven't access to the source code of the polling server